# Cakephp 2: need help on misconfiguration with PDOStatement

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli, cakephp-2.0

I've got a problem with a request on Cakephp 2. When I try to put a `'` or `?` in a string I get the error message

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
>
> [17:05:44] Root: #0 /var/home/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(436): PDOStatement->execute(Array)

This works on my local computer and all the local computers I've tried (all with WAMP installed). Only on the publication server do I get this issue.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this error by upgrading php to 5.3.6

the version of 5.2 my old mamp was using had this bug:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44251

Comment: Thanks for the link ! Fixed it !

Answer (score 0):

I got this too.  What version of Cake2 are you using? Upgrading to the latest (2.0.5) fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm in 2.0.4. I will try the update to 2.0.5 and i come back to you.

Comment: apologies, This isn't correct.  I'm still getting an error in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a raw query beware of any ?s you may have in a comment. Looks like the PDO lib will try to replace those.